# Identify this genre that features EDM beats with sung vocals?

Tags: electronic-music, identify-this-genre

I like music with beats (like in EDM) and vocals like in [The Weeknd's *Can't Feel My Face*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KEI4qSrkPAs).

Comment: Beat and vocals describe a huge chunk of music can you be more specific in your description?

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia, The Weeknd is most closely associated with a style sometimes called [PBR&B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBR%26B) (or alt R&B), a hip-hop and EDM influenced contemporary take on R&B ("Rhythm and Blues," the catch-all term for sung music styles most closely associated with urban black American artists).  You might also look into [electropop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electropop), and its subgenres, such as [electroswing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electro_swing) and [futurepop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futurepop).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, first and foremost, that it's just **Pop**, 2015 style!

Over the last 25 years, mainstream pop music has incorporated more and more influences from EDM, hip-hop, and contemporary R&B, to an extent that many tracks released by mainstream artists have production that blends these (and other) genres quite seamlessly.

Justin Bieber is as close as you can get to a mainstream pop artist, but his recent single *What Do You Mean?* could be described pefectly as 'EDM beats with sung vocals'.